# Windows 7 suspend failed after Ubuntu 12.04 installation

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, windows-7, suspend, bootloader

HP 6235.fr
- 2 Hard Disk
- 1 NVDIA GT220

1. Clean installation of Windows 7 on first hard disk.

   Windows 7 suspend/wake up is working.
2. Clean installation of Ubuntu 12.04 from web ISO image on second hard disk.

   Windows 7 suspend/wake up is working.
3. Software update of Ubuntu 12.04 (in particular, GRUB is also updated).

   Windows 7 suspend is not working anymore (login screen is coming back ...).

Is there any solution to this problem?

N.B: If Windows 7 is booted via NT loader and not with GRUB, suspend/wake up is working.

Comment: How are you booting via "NT loader"? I believe grub chainloads the Windows 7 bootloader...

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same issue.

I fixed it by making the Windows system drive (usually `C:`) active using any partitioning utility (like `diskpart`).

Answer (score 1):

I have grub chainloading 7 and suspend works fine.

I would suggest updating your firmware.

The actual procedure for flashing the BIOS varies from vendor to vendor, but here are some relevant posts from the stack network:

[What is flashing the BIOS?](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/04/03/what-is-flashing-the-bios/)
[How do I flash a particular machine?](https://superuser.com/questions/443159/how-do-i-update-the-bios-on-my-motherboard-asus-p8z77-v-lx)

It bears noting that some support online flashing/updates, but these are more often hobbyist motherboards than stock boards from Dell/HP.

Others you have to boot from separate media to run a BIOS update.